# How to set value input() function in Brython, not confirm dialog?

Tags: brython

My code:

```
a = input()
print(a)
```

I want set value from input not confirm dialog.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: give me more details, pls!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that'll work.
Brython translates to JavaScript, which will run in the browser in event driven mode.
This doesn't allow blocking console input.

Skulpt found a solution for that:

https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/blob/master/doc/suspensions.txt

But if you want to do browser programming, probably the best is to use HTML inputs. A.f.i.k. Brython can cooperate with those.